# Como retornar a primeira vogal de varias palavras em uma lista?

Tags: python, string, lista, loop, tupla

O código está parcialmente feito, porém ele retorna apenas as vogais encontradas em cada palavra.

Como eu poderia retornar apenas a primeira vogal de cada palavra?

```
palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma',)
vogais = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for palavras in palavras:
print(f'\nPalavra {palavras}', end=' ')
for letra in palavras:
    if letra in vogais:
        print(letra, end=' ')
```

Resultado:

```
Palavra boi o i 

Palavra vaca a a 

Palavra macaco a a o 

Palavra ovelha o e a 

Palavra lesma e a 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Reformulando a pergunta....

O intuito é aprender como manipular os elementos da string letra.

Por exemplo, como poderia retornar a ultima vogal das palavras?

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 5):

insira um break após o print da volgal:

```
palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma',)
vogais = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for palavras in palavras:
    print(f'\nPalavra {palavras}', end=' ')
    for letra in palavras:
        if letra in vogais:
            print(letra, end=' ')
            break
```

e terá resolvido o problema!

Comment: Muito obrigado Juliano!

Com essa pergunta, eu estava tentando aprender, como manipular os elementos da string letras.

Por exemplo, saberia dizer como eu traria a ultima vogal de cada letra?

Comment: voce pode inverter a palavra e continuar retornando a primeira vogal no caso:
palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma',)
vogais = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for palavras in palavras:
    print(f'\nPalavra {palavras}', end=' ')
    for letra in palavras[::-1]:
        if letra in vogais:
            
            print(letra, end=' ')
            break

Comment: caso você pretenda utilizar as outras posições das vogais aconselho a criar uma lista com as vogais de cada palavra, assim conseguindo acessar a posição de caca uma delas quando necessário:

palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma',)
vogais = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for palavras in palavras:
    nvogais=[]
    print(f'\nPalavra {palavras}', end=' ')
    for letra in palavras:
        if letra in vogais:
            nvogais.append(letra)

    print(nvogais[x], end=' ')

onde x é a posição da vogal desejada

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente Juliano! consegui entender um pouco mais sobre as manipulações desses elementos

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma',)

for palavra in palavras:
    try:
        print('Palavra ' , palavra , re.findall(r'a|e|i|o|u', palavra)[0])
    except:
        print('Palavra ' , palavra , ' não contém vogal')
```

Com a biblioteca 're' você consegue pegar padrões na stirng, e ela vai te retornar os matches.
Por exemplo, a palavra **macaco** vai te retornar: **['a', 'a', 'o']**

Para acessar o primeiro elemento, basta acessar o índice **[0]**. Caso queira o último elemento, como respondeu na pergunta acima, acesse com **[-1]**, que vai te retornar o último elemento da lista.

Adicione um Try Except para caso de não haver vogais em uma palavra, logo é retornado uma lista vazia, e ao tentar acessar um índice vai estourar um erro.

Comment: Muito obrigado Matheus! Ótima referencia para strings, vou estudar um pouco mais essa biblioteca.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizando o seguinte código:

```
palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma')

for palavra in palavras:
    for letra in palavra:
        if letra in 'aeiou':
            print(f'Para "{palavra}" a primeira vogal é: "{letra}"')
            break
```

Observe que neste código não utilizei uma lista contendo as vogais. Neste caso utilizei uma sequencia de strings contendo as **5 vogais** localizada na linha do bloco `"if"`.

Para que o código exiba **apenas** a primeira vogal é necessário que o segundo bloco `for` seja interrompido logo após o bloco if ter encontrado a primeira vogal da respectiva palavra e, para isso, é necessário utilizarmos o `break`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Solkarped!

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa é aplicar um filtro em suas strings permitindo que passem apenas as vogais e coletar as informações.

A ideia do algoritmo é verificar cada palavra de sua [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) e fazer uma busca [case insensitive](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/case_insensitive) por vogais, o que nada mais é uma que uma busca tipográfica indiferente ao caixa ou seja o algoritmo é indiferente a maiúsculas e minúsculas. Por exemplo, para o algoritmo *"vaca"* e *"VACA"* são a mesma palavra e o sistema identifica as duas ocorrências da mesma vogal *"a"* o que não acontece num algoritmo [case sensitive](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/case_sensitive) por exemplo para para um algoritmo sensível ao caixa cujo o parâmetro de busca seja *`aeiou`* seria retornado que a palavra *"VACA"* não possui vogais.

Para fazer a busca por vogais insensível ao caixa é usado o método [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) que converte todos os caracteres alfabéticos de uma string para letras minúsculas.

A busca em si é feita através de uma filtragem onde a cada palavra analisada e sujeitada a função built in [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) que nada mais faz que aplicar uma função `function` a um dos elementos [iterável](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) `iterable` e caso o retorno dessa função seja `True` o elemento avaliado aprovado pelo filtro caso contrário é rejeitado.

Nessa solução a função passada para filter é uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) que nada mais é a definição de uma função anônima criada por meio da palavra-chave `lambda`. ao invés de algo como:

```
def funcao_filtro(letra):
     return letra in vogais

filter(funcao_filtro , p)
```

Preferi fazer algo mais enxuto:

```
filter(lambda l: l in vogais, p)
```

Após isso vem a parte mais simples do algoritmo que é juntar o resultado da filtragem com [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) e fazer a análise no resultado.

Solução:

```
palavras = ('boi', 'vaca', 'macaco', 'ovelha', 'lesma', "kkk")
vogais = 'aeiou'

#Para cada palavra na tupla de palavras...
for palavra in palavras:
    #Converte as letras da palavra para minúscula para fazer a filtragem case-insensitive e evitar excessões.
    p = palavra.lower()   
    #Obtem o resultado da filtragem da palavra deixando apenas as vogais.
    r = "".join(filter(lambda l: l in vogais, p))
    #Compara o tamanho do resultado...
    if len(r) == 0:
        #...se igual a 0.
        msg = f'A palavra "{p}" não não possui vogais.'
    else:
        #... se maior que 0.
        msg = f'A palavra é "{p}":\n'
        msg += f'{" "*2}• a palavra possui {len(r)} vogais "{r}"\n' 
        msg += f'{" "*2}• a primeira vogal é "{r[0]}"\n'
        msg += f'{" "*2}• a última vogal é "{r[-1]}"'
    #Imprime a mensagem informando o resultado.
    print(msg)
```

Resultando:

```php
A palavra é "boi":
  • a palavra possui 2 vogais "oi"
  • a primeira vogal é "o"
  • a última vogal é "i".
A palavra é "vaca":
  • a palavra possui 2 vogais "aa"
  • a primeira vogal é "a"
  • a última vogal é "a".
A palavra é "macaco":
  • a palavra possui 3 vogais "aao"
  • a primeira vogal é "a"
  • a última vogal é "o".
A palavra é "ovelha":
  • a palavra possui 3 vogais "oea"
  • a primeira vogal é "o"
  • a última vogal é "a".
A palavra é "lesma":
  • a palavra possui 2 vogais "ea"
  • a primeira vogal é "e"
  • a última vogal é "a".
A palavra é "kkk" e não possui vogais.
```

Comment: Muito legal essa solução, eu não conhecia a função LAMBDA, vou estudar mais sobre ela. 
Muito Obrigado Augusto!